# Vertical align with div into div using css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How could I make an vertical align of '10:00" and the gliphs on right side of thewe markup, into parent div?
An optional horizontal align as well will be  appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39516/

//markup

```
<div class="container" style="outline: 1px solid orange;">
<div class="col-sm-10 bg-danger">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 bg-info">
    10:00
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        Clique aqui para agendar
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        Consulta
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        Parando
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 " >
  <div><i class="pull-right glyphicon" class="glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-lock pull-right"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-user pull-right"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

//css

```
import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your styles:

```
.container,
.container > .col-sm-10 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39518/)